# brownie-config remappings error when trying to import from chainlink

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity, brownie

I am trying to import this code

```
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";
```

but "Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol" not found: File import callback not supported" error messages appear when i try to compile.

My brownie-config.yaml file has

```
dependencies:
  # - <organization/repo>@<version>
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'
```

but the code still results in the same error. Are there any fixes to this?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that running `brownie compile` failed to install the dependencies specified in `brownie-yaml.config`. You can check brownie installed package with:

```
$ brownie pm list
```

If the package is missing, you need to install the package first:

```
$ brownie pm install smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
```

Then, compile the project again: (the -a flag is optional, it is to force recompile all contracts)

```
$ brownie compile -a
```

The error should be gone, since now we correctly install the dependency first before compiling the contracts

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing: `npm install @chainlink/contracts --save`

and in the yaml file doing:[image]